# Get index of two consecutive upper case characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation, string-parsing

I am trying to separate a `city/state/zip` field into the city, state, and zip. Normally I would do this with `charindex` of `','` to get the city and state, and `isnumeric` and `right()` for the zip.

This will work fine for the zip, but most of the rows in the data I am working with now have no commas `City ST Zip`. Is there a way to identify the index of two upper case characters?

If not, does anybody have a better idea than just a case statement checking for each state individually?

**EDIT:** I found the PATINDEX/COLLATE option to work fairly intermittently. See my answer below.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: Could you not use `PATINDEX('[A-Z][A-Z]', [column_to_search])`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO He didn't say there was a problem with code he has written, he said he doesn't know how to accomplish what he wants to do.  I think "Normally I would do this with " shows that he has put some thought into it himself, but didn't include such code because it's obviously not a solution and would probably mislead the question.

Comment: @AaronLS At the least, showing a sample with expected results is required.

Comment: @Lankymart Great idea, but searching in sql server is not case sensitive, so that just returns 0 all the time.

Comment: @Pat case sensitivity is based on the collation you have, so you can use PATINDEX if you explicitly state a case sensitive collation.

Comment: @Pat It is by default by you can force the collation but couldn't get it to work properly - `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`

Comment: Should it look something like this? `patindex('[A-Z][A-Z]',CityStZip COLLATE Latin1_general_cs_as)` That still returns all 0's.

Comment: @Pat Just consider this approach will be fragile/buggy. When you have cities with a two letter abbreviation where someone entered something like "Township of ST Mary, MI 12345".  You'd have better results if you had a table of states with an abbreviations column.  There is a lot of other uses for such a table and you can find scripts to generate one for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the PATINDEX/COLLATE option to work fairly intermittently. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
--get rid of the sparsely used commas
--get rid of the duplicate spaces
update MyTable set
    CityStZip= 
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(CityStZip,'   ',' '),
                '  ',' '),
            ',','')

select
    --check if state and zip are there and then grab the city
    case when isNumeric(right(CityStZip,1))=1
            then left(CityStZip,len(CityStZip)-charindex(' ',reverse(CityStZip),
                                        charindex(' ',reverse(CityStZip))+1)+1)
        --no zip. check for state
        when left(right(CityStZip,3),1) = ' '
            then left(CityStZip,len(CityStZip)-charIndex(' ',reverse(CityStZip)))
        else CityStZip
        end as City,
    --check if zip is there and then grab the city
    case when isNumeric(right(CityStZip,1))=1
            then substring(CityStZip,
                    len(CityStZip)-charindex(' ',reverse(CityStZip),
                                                charindex(' ',reverse(CityStZip))+1)+2,
                    2)
        --no zip. check if 3rd to last char is a space and grab the last two chars
        when left(right(CityStZip,3),1) = ' '
            then right(CityStZip,2)
        end as [State],
    --grab everything after the last space if the last character is numeric
    case when isNumeric(right(CityStZip,1))=1
            then substring(CityStZip,
                    len(CityStZip)-charindex(' ',reverse(CityStZip))+1,
                    charindex(' ',reverse(CityStZip)))
        end as Zip
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason why `PATINDEX` appears to work intermittently is that you cannot use a character range (i.e. `A-Z`) to accomplish a case-sensitive search, even if using a case-sensitive collation. The issue is that character ranges work like sorting, and case-sensitive sorting groups the upper-case letters with their lower-case equivalents, just like it would be ordered in a dictionary. Range sorting is really: a,A,b,B,c,C,d,D,etc. Or, depending on the collation, it might be: A,a,B,b,C,c,D,d,etc (there are 31 Collations that sort upper-case first). When doing this in a case-sensitive collation, that merely groups all `A` entries together, separate from the `a` entries, whereas in a case-*in*sensitive sort they would be intermixed.

But if you specify each of the letters individually (hence not using a range), then it will work as expected:

```
PATINDEX(N'%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%',
     [CityStZip] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS)
```

The reason that `PATINDEX` and `LIKE` (both of which allow for a single character class of `[A-Z]`) work this way is that the `[start-end]` syntax is *not* a Regular Expression. Many people claim that `PATINDEX` and `LIKE` support "limited" RegEx due to supporting this syntax, but that is not true. It is merely a very similar (and a confusingly similar) syntax to RegEx where `[A-Z]` would normally *not* include any lower-case matches.

Of course, if you are guaranteed to only be searching on the US-English letters of A-Z, then a binary collation (i.e. one ending in `_BIN2`; don't use ones ending in `_BIN` as they have been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 was introduced, I believe) should work.

```
PATINDEX(N'%[A-Z][A-Z]%', [CityStZip] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2)
```

---

For more details about case-sensitive matching, especially in regards to including Unicode / NVARCHAR data, please see my related answer on DBA.StackExchange:

[How to find values with multiple consecutive upper case characters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122612/how-to-find-values-with-multiple-consecutive-upper-case-characters/122625#122625)

Answer (score 4):

[PATINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) should work for you:

```
PATINDEX('% [A-Z][A-Z] %', A COLLATE Latin1_general_cs_as)
```

So your full extract would be something like:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  i = PATINDEX('% [A-Z][A-Z] %', A COLLATE Latin1_general_cs_as) + 1,
            A
    FROM    (VALUES 
                ('City ST Zip'),
                ('Another City ST Zip'),
                ('City, with comma ST Zip')
            ) t (A)
)
SELECT  City = LEFT(A, i - 2),
        State = SUBSTRING(A, i, 2),
        Zip = SUBSTRING(A, i + 3, LEN(A))
FROM    CTE;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13208)**

Comment: Character ranges (i.e. `[A-Z]` ), even with a case-sensitive collation, do not work as one would usually expect. Although in this particular case a `_BIN2` collation probably would work. Please see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34076245/577765) for details.

Answer (score 2):

If you have zip code and state at the end of the string, then this might work:

```
select right(address, 5) as zip,
       left(right(address, 8), 2) as state,
       left(address, len(address) - 9) as city
```

You can start by removing the commas and double spaces from the address.

Comment: Unfortunately, the zip codes are not consistently there. Neither are the states or I would do something like this. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of states(which you should) with a column of the abbreviations you can do things like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Addresses a
INNER JOIN States s ON
a.CityStateZip Like '% ' + s.UpperCaseAbbreviation + ' %' --space on either side of abbreviation
```

You can make it work for both commas and spaces:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Addresses a
INNER JOIN States s ON
Replace(a.CityStateZip, ',' , ' ') Like '% ' + s.UpperCaseAbbreviation + ' %'
```